# Google Script - Convert a string to coded score

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google form that I am trying to code the qualitative answers to a numeric scale while preserving the qualitative responses for documentation.

My response sheet currently looks like this:
[image]

Where the original answers are in columns D, F, H, J, and L, and I have added columns for these to be coded into scores from -3 to 3 with a 0 option for "unknown / unsure". Currently I have added a drawing to the sheet and assigned a script to this that I want to loop through rows and look at the qualitative answers and code them to the correct qualitative score in the following column (i.e., if column D says "Agree" it should add a 2 as the score in column E).

If the script was working correctly it should look like this:
[image]

Here is the google sheet I'm working with:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GTSf0_GYyG5XI0-bJtQ2IwTAEyWcdmkGeSdqmnWoRs/edit#gid=0

Below is a copy of the script I have at this point:

```
function score() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var i = 4; i < data.length; i++){
  if(data[i][9] == "")
      {
        break;
      }
      else
      {
          for(var x = 9; x < sheet.getLastColumn(); x++)
          {
            if(data[i][x] == "Strongly Agree")
            {
              sheet.getRange(i,x+1).setValue("3");
            }
            if(data[i][x] == "Agree")
            {
              sheet.getRange(i,x+1).setValue("2");
            }
            if(data[i][x] == "Somewhat Agree")
            {
              sheet.getRange(i+1,x+1).setValue("1");
            }
            if(data[i][x] == "Unsure / Unknown")
            {
              sheet.getRange(i+1,x+1).setValue("0");
            }
            if(data[i][x] == "Somewhat Disagree")
            {
              sheet.getRange(i+1,x+1).setValue("-1");
            }
            if(data[i][x] == "Disagree")
            {
              sheet.getRange(i+1,x+1).setValue("-2");
            }
            if(data[i][x] == "Strongly Disagree")
            {
              sheet.getRange(i+1,x+1).setValue("-3");
            }
            
            
          }
      }
  }
  
}
```

How can I get this to pull correctly? Is there an alternative to having the "button" that needs pushed everytime and instead just have answers code as new ones are submitted?

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data, your question may be closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `setValue` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- In your situation, I thought that when `var obj = { "Somewhat Agree": 0, "Somewhat Agree": 1, "Agree": 2, "Strongly Agree": 3, "Somewhat Disagree": -1, "Disagree": -2, "Strongly Disagree": -3 }` is prepared, the script might be a bit simpler.

When these points are reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function score() {
  // This object was created from your showing script.
  var obj = { "Somewhat Agree": 0, "Somewhat Agree": 1, "Agree": 2, "Strongly Agree": 3, "Somewhat Disagree": -1, "Disagree": -2, "Strongly Disagree": -3 };

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var [, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values = data.map(r => {
    r.forEach((c, j, a) => {
      if (obj[c]) a[j + 1] = obj[c];
    });
    return r;
  });
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, `Score` is put to the right side of `Question #` by checking the value of `Question #` using `obj`.

#### Note:

- As an additional information, when I saw your Spreadsheet and your showing script, in your Spreadsheet, the data is "D2:M". But, it seems that the script uses "J5:M". I thought that this might be the reason for the issue with your script. If your script is modified for your showing Spreadsheet, how about the following modification? But, I think that the process cost of this modified script is higher than that of the above one. Please be careful about this.

  ```
    function score() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var x = 3; x < sheet.getLastColumn(); x++) {
          console.log(data[i][x])
          if (data[i][x] == "Strongly Agree") {
            sheet.getRange(i + 1, x + 2).setValue("3");
          }
          if (data[i][x] == "Agree") {
            sheet.getRange(i + 1, x + 2).setValue("2");
          }
          if (data[i][x] == "Somewhat Agree") {
            sheet.getRange(i + 1, x + 2).setValue("1");
          }
          if (data[i][x] == "Unsure / Unknown") {
            sheet.getRange(i + 1, x + 2).setValue("0");
          }
          if (data[i][x] == "Somewhat Disagree") {
            sheet.getRange(i + 1, x + 2).setValue("-1");
          }
          if (data[i][x] == "Disagree") {
            sheet.getRange(i + 1, x + 2).setValue("-2");
          }
          if (data[i][x] == "Strongly Disagree") {
            sheet.getRange(i + 1, x + 2).setValue("-3");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: That worked great! Would you mind explaining the lines where you assign var [, ...data] down so I can possibly adjust this script to other future projects and understand what needs updated?

Comment: @data_life Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `var [, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`, in this case, `data` is retrieved with the destructuring assignment. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) The rows after row 2 are retrieved as `data`. And, in the loop of map and forEach, the value is searched using `obj`, and when the value is found, the number is put to the right side of the cell. And, `values` is put into the cells. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @data_life When I saw your showing Spreadsheet and the values you want to check, I understood that the values you want to check are unique values in the cell values. So, I used this situation. If you want to change the values of "Somewhat Agree", "Somewhat Agree" and so so on, please modify `obj` to your expected values.

Comment: @data_life As additional information, I added one more modified script by modifying your showing script using your showing Spreadsheet. If that was useful for understanding the process. I'm glad.

Comment: @data_life From `That worked great`, if your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer